# Why can't use beginform with ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to send id my load page and how can ı send id and load another page ?

MY error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
I now this error syntax error but ı am tried everything , ı am new in ajax and mvc

this is my code :

```
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url : "http://localhost:9000/api/Customer/CustomerList",
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#customerList").DataTable({
                     pageLength:50,
                     destroy: true,
                     "data": data,
                     "columns": [
                         { "data": "CustID"},
                         {
                             "data":   function send(data) {
                                 return "@using (Html.BeginForm("CustomerList", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" })) {<input type='submit' value=" + data.custID + " />}";
                              }
                         }
                     ]
                 });
             },
             error: function (data) {
                 alert("CustomerList");
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Razor syntax has to be parsed before it works. If you inspect the output of your page, you will never find the "Html.BeginForm" tag/code.

You code shows you are getting the CustomerList using an ajax request. You can simply use the same technique to post the id when the button is clicked.

```
return "<input type='submit' onClick='sendID(" + data.custID )'/>";
```

the sendID function could look something like this

function sendID(customerID){

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: {custID: customerID},
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url : "http://localhost:9000/api/Customer/GetCustomer", // your endpoint url here
         success: function (data) {
              // do something
         });
         },
         error: function (data) {
             alert("Could not send customerid");
         }
     });
```

}

This is untested code.